# How can I locate values.xml?

Tags: android

I recently purchased a MacBook Pro and downloaded the latest version of android studio after import an old project to my android studio on this new Mac, I had a lot of errors have been able to fix but there's this error which I can't seem to find an answer to it. It says

error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found., sources=[/Users/acountofUser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/97d47f978f7d2c601194030528adee8d/res/values/values.xml:1423:5-1464:13], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

This is how my style.xml looks like

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

Suggestions says I should just remove the '@' sign in front of @android:attr. But the issue is I can't even find where the values.xml and on top of it all remove the '@' sign.

Comment: My guess is that your `compileSdkVersion` is lower than `27`. To use `appcompat-v7:27.0.2`, you need to set your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27.

Comment: Yes my compilSdkVersion is 27 and targetSdkVersion is also 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the solution may defer, in my case I made sure all third party libraries that i'm using is updated. Hence the error vanished.

Answer (score 0):

If in your `styles.xml` you have a line like:

```
<item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/something</item>
```

remove `@` from `@android`

Comment: I have edited my question and added how my styles.xml looks like. I don't have anything like <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/something</item> in there

Comment: @chevi99 Do you use any 3d party libraries?

Comment: Yes I'm using hdendof circle imageView and a searchableSpinner libraries

Comment: @chevi99 there is a possibility that one of these libraries contain this attribute. If possible,  for testing, remove them, one at a time and try again.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Actually i upgraded these libraries to their latest version and everything worked fine.